# Voltage Drop on I/O Pin of AVR Tiny Micro-controller

Tags: microcontroller, io, attiny85

[image][image]I am working on a project based on AVR Tiny85 Microcontroller interfacing with an RGB LED. In order to test the Tiny Board I/O pins I have written a sample test code to toggle I/O.

**Test Code**

```
#include <avr/io.h>     
#include <util/delay.h>

// This program will turn the LEDs on for 100ms, 
// then off for 200ms, endlessly.

int main(void)
{
  // Set Port B pins for 3 and 4 as outputs
  // PORTB bit 3 = physical pin #2 on the ATTINY85
  // PORTB bit 4 = physical pin #3 on the ATTINY85

  DDRB = 0x18;  // In binary this is 0001 1000 (note that is bit 3 and 4)
  // AVR-GCC also would accept 0b00011000, by the way.

 // Set up a forever loop 
 for ( ; 1==1 ; )  // loop while 1 equals 1
  {
    // Set Port B pins for 3 and 4 as HIGH (i.e. turn the LEDs on)
    PORTB = 0x18;   // If we wanted only PB4 on, it'd be PORTB=0x10

    // Use a function (defined in delay.h) to pause 500 milliseconds
    _delay_ms(500);

    // Set PORTB to be all LOWs (i.e. turn the LEDs off)
    PORTB = 0x00;

    // Delay for a 500ms
    _delay_ms(500);
  }

return 1;
}
```

**Issues:**

When I am driving the I/O pin as 1 or 0 the output should reach the Vcc or GND respectively. But when I connect the LED to GND and one of these I/Os (Pin 3 and 4), the pin drives the LED up to VCC, but for the off condition, the I/O still has some voltage relative to GND. In this case, LED is not completely turned off.

What could be the possible reason for this issue?
Please advice

Thank you

**Scope Output:**

I have changed the delay time to 500 msec to get a visual indication of ON and OFF state

**Schamatic:**

Comment: What resistance are you using?

Comment: Do you have an oscilloscope waveform of LED voltage? The 100ms off time is too short to judge visually.

Comment: Maybe try a bare resistor as a sanity check?

Comment: Did you remember to disconnect the programmer?

Comment: I have tried with another controller with the same code and it works fine irrespective of the programmer connection.

Comment: Could you provide a schematic of how you wired things up _exactly_? This includes details about the ground connection to the attiny and to the led(s), and where your oscilloscope probes are attached. A picture might provide helpful clues, too.

Comment: Those are very strange measurement points.

Comment: Have you left an internal pullup turned on? You say it's specific to this chip and swapping the chip introduces the problem?

Comment: Yes, it is. As I am using another Attiny 85 chip it works fine, but one of the chips giving me this issue. I am interested in knowing the cause.

Comment: If you do a full chip erase and program the fuses, flash, and EEPROM the same as the working one and it still shows erroneous behavior then the answer is easy: the chip is broken.

Comment: Fuses? Specifically, CKOUT?

Comment: You have pull-up resistor on top LED, that's alone will give some voltage on test pin regardless of pin state. You don't need pull-up to drive the LED anyway, current limiting resistor is must and you have it.

Comment: I am not changing any setting of Fuses during the programming, i am taking it as default set by Atmel Studio.

Comment: The pull-up register I have used because I am using that pin as an Input connected to the Switch. In order to test the I/O behaviour, I have added a LED externally.

Comment: Atmel Studio does not change, or program, any fuses "by default". (Except "debug wire".) So if someone once set the fuse wrong, it will stay like that until someone explicitly changes it.

Comment: Agree. It works fine with other chip not the one with fault.

Comment: Oh, it's only with one particular attiny85? In that case, my money is on ESD damage.

Comment: Your program is correct, and schematic should work. However, this may be caused due to residual flux between the pins. You might want to check your hardware thoroughly, and also cross-check the connections and compare with the schematic. If you are testing on a breadboard, this may also be due to parasitic capacitance, or noise from a nearby source. Longer wires pick up noise more easily.